# Narrow range of binary response variable in xgboost

Tags: r, xgboost

I'm using xgboost (version 0.6-4 for R version 3.4.2) for a binary classification problem. I'm finding that the response variable is mostly confined to a very narrow range. This seems to be independent of the hyperparameters (`eta`, `max_depth`, and `nround`) that I choose for training.

To illustrate the problem, I've explicitly created nested for-loops to store the range of the response variable for a variety of hyperparameter sets:

```
pred_df <- data_frame(eta = numeric(0),
                  depth = numeric(0),
                  round = numeric(0),
                  min_score = numeric(0),
                  first_quart = numeric(0),
                  median = numeric(0),
                  mean = numeric(0),
                  third_quart = numeric(0),
                  max = numeric(0)
                  )
for (this_eta in c(1.0, 0.7, 0.4, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001))
{
  for (this_depth in seq(4, 16, 2))
  {
    for (this_round in c(5, 10, 25, 75, 150))
    {
      dtrain    <- xgb.DMatrix(data = data.matrix(X_train), label = Y_train)
      xgb_model <- xgboost(data = dtrain, eta = this_eta, max_depth = this_depth,
                           nround = this_round, objective = "binary:logistic",
                           verbose = 0, save_period = NULL, nthread = 4)
      y_pred     <- predict(xgb_model, data.matrix(X_test))
      summ <- summary(y_pred)
      this_entry <- data_frame(eta = this_eta,
                               depth = this_depth,
                               round = this_round,
                               min_score = as.numeric(summ[1]),
                               first_quart = as.numeric(summ[2]),
                               median = as.numeric(summ[3]),
                               mean = as.numeric(summ[4]),
                               third_quart = as.numeric(summ[5]),
                               max = as.numeric(summ[6])
                               )
      pred_df <- bind_rows(pred_df, this_entry)
    }
  }
}
```

So, `pred_df` is just a data frame for storing the summaries of the response variable.

Let's add another variable to help show the problem:

```
pred_df <- mutate(pred_df, quartile_diff = round(third_quart - first_quart, 3))
```

The 1st and 3rd quartiles are very close to each other, indicating that the range of the response variable is very compressed:

```
> summary(pred_df$quartile_diff)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
0.00000 0.01625 0.04600 0.05498 0.09400 0.14600
```

But this narrow range shifts around quite a bit:

```
> summary(pred_df$median)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
0.0008036 0.0107366 0.0590362 0.1743002 0.4010580 0.4977787
```

For any particular set of hyperparameters, this range is much closer to the minimum response than to the maximum.

In case you are wondering, `X_train` has 2856 cases with 33 predictors. `X_test` has 1209 cases. I'm a little concerned about underfitting with such a small number of predictors, but I don't know if that's responsible for this.

Any ideas what might be causing such a problem? I need my response variable to be a probability, hence the use of `objective = "binary:logistic"`.

EDIT: I've been asked about the counts of outcomes in the training data. Here they are:

```
> table(Y_train)
Y_train
   0    1 
2434  422
```

Comment: One way to check whether this is reasonable is to look at the rate of positive outcomes in the data. Is it near 5%? On the whole, this range actually looks fine to me. I think you just have a signal that isn't especially predictable, and it is probably the case of the most of your data has a low likelihood of being in the positive group.

Comment: Sorry, I should have given the table of `Y_train`. I've edited my answer to include that.

Comment: Yeah, this still seems reasonable to me. Often with binary classifications there are a few points tat have a really high likelihood, and then a high, narrow peak of people who are pretty much crowded around the bottom. Your results suggest to me that that's the case here. I don't think xgboost is an issue.

Comment: I agree with @data princess. One way to remedy the situation is to set `scale_pos_weight` to between 5 to 10 this will increase the weight of the positive group subjects (higher loss for wrong prediction of rare events). Other ways include sub or over sampling, SMOTE or ROSE [Here](https://topepo.github.io/caret/subsampling-for-class-imbalances.html) is a solid resource.